# How would I sync up multiple java.awt.robot keyPresses?

Tags: java, timing, awtrobot

I'm trying to setup a program that allows me to feed a musical score and get the Robot to sync up multiple key presses to play the song on a virtual piano. Everything is formatted correctly and the robot presses the right buttons in the right order, but it's not syncing up at all. Songs will have multiple notes played at the same time, so I'm having it read multiple bars one character at a time, but some will have rests when the others have notes and I think that's what's messing up the timing, I not entirely sure though and I also don't know how I would fix this.

Code snippet I'm dealing with:

```
        //making robot press buttons cause I'm too prideful to just use a MIDI player
        for (int o =0;o<alist.get(0).size();o++) {
            for (int q=0;q<Pianos;q++) {
                if (alist.get(q).get(o).equals("R")) {
                    System.out.println("rest here");
                }else if (alist.get(q).get(o).equals("c2")) {
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
                }else if (alist.get(q).get(o).equals("C2")) {
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                } (... all the other notes in between C2 and c7...)
                else if (alist.get(q).get(o).equals("c7")) {
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_M);
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(rest);
        }
```

alist is an arraylists of arraylists, each arraylist is one bar of the song, with each string within being either a note to play or a rest. Pianos is the number of these bars. Rest is an arbitrary amount of ms.

I tried the code above and I thought the Thread.sleep(rest); at the end would make it so that whatever note the robot played would take the same amount of time, even if it was a rest. Instead, the timing is messed up everytime I use the program.

Comment: So, you need some kind of solution which would allow for a key press to be maintained for a duration of time, but while still allowing other keys to be pressed - you also need a period of time in which nothing is pressed.  I would suggest that your current approach is to limited.  Instead, what you want is a series of "events" which need to be "triggered" and which can execute independently of others (rests may be the exception).

Comment: This would suggest a concept of a "key" and "delay". In order to "play" the event, you'd probably need some kind of thread that could trigger the release after the delay.  In animation terms, this begins to form a "time lime", where an event would be trigged at some point in time and, independently of other keys, would play for a period of time

Comment: You may also need a concept of a "chord", where multiple keys are played simultanously

Comment: I like the idea of triggerable events, but I have no idea how I would make multiple lines of code run at once. But thankfully I won't have to deal with rests messing up the other lines as that's dealt with in the formatting stage.